# How to make an icon appear invisible without using a clear picture

Tags: java, icons, imageicon

I am making a program but the default Java icon looks really ugly, i want it so that the icon is clear without using any clear pictures, I'm using this code 
`f.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("pic.png").getImage());`
 so is there a way to do it? Or do i have to stick with a clear image?

Comment: By "clear" do you mean translucent or semitransparent?

Comment: My first thought is, "why are you trying to write code to display an invisible icon?"  I mean, why bother writing any code?  But I suspect your title and the wording of your question need to be made clearer (although the part about the Java icon being ugly is pretty clear already).

Comment: OK what i mean is, is there a way to remove the default icon without using a clear image file(because clear image files display as nothing in java, hence making the icon non-visible)?

Comment: By clear i mean transparent so nothing at all.

Comment: Have a look at [DaniWeb - ImageIcon and Transparency](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/414697/imageicon-and-transparency). That might be what you're looking for.